# Connecting mirrored vertices with edges and then filling in faces between the edges without a million clicks? (screenshots + cleaner explain in post)

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode

Okay so I'm creating a sort of arena/stadium/symmetrical shape for a game using curves. I basically make a cyclical curve to make a floor, duplicate it and move it up to make a ceiling, turn it into a mesh, then bridge those 2 edge loops to make the walls. That gives me a mesh like this without any problems:
[image: figure 1 with vertices]
The problem here is creating the ceilings and floor. I can't find a (relatively) automatic way to connect the vertices across the X axis with each other. This is the end result I'm trying to achieve via a tool or maybe plugin or just some sort of function:
[image: figure 2]
So here, I have literally clicked on a vertex, moved my camera across the X axis, clicked on the other vertex, and hit F to make an edge between them. I did that for every vertex on that edge loop. Then I clicked on 2 edges at a time, hitting F again to fill in the faces. Now I'm no expert, but surely this is a suuuuuuper amateur scrubby way to do things. And seeing as how I need to make multiple iterations of this kind of shape to see what works in game and what doesn't, experimenting with different shapes/modifications etc. etc. etc., I mean it's obviously just not realistic to do this every time I want to see how a new shape of arena plays out. So in the interest of learning how actual 3d artists do things, and trying to find a way of doing things that doesn't turn my wrist bones to dust by christmas, I thought I would pose this problem to some people with brains lol. pls help: is there a way to achieve this that doesn't involve manually clicking on every single vertex and edge ~2 times? Some sort of function/tool/maybe even add-on or plugin or script I could use?.

Some things I've tried that haven't worked (no screenshots cause it seems kinda spammy, post is long enough lol):

-I cannot use bridge edge loops because I'm creating 1 face from 1 edge loop.

-I cannot hit F for fill because this gives me a very wonky N-gon, and triangulating or otherwise subdividing that face produces results significantly different in shape from the second image I posted, results that would not play nice with collision in a game engine (or look good for that matter, especially near the edges and corners.

-Grid fill produces a very warped result, which does look pretty cool, and it probably would technically work with collision, but it isn't flat enough for those collision to be predictable by a player which would be very frustrating (it'd be like playing basketball on a court that got warped by water; looks kinda trippy and neat but the ball is not gunna bounce back up to your hand when you dribble it, it's gunna hit off some random bump you could barely see and rocket to the side).

I was kinda hoping just writing this post would help me think of something else I could try but it hasn't -.- so any help would be very very appreciated. Anyway thank you for reading <3 I hope I've explained the problem well enough to understand, my knowledge of 3d modelling is pretty limited so I feel like I'm missing something that's probably quite obvious to someone more experienced. If I don't respond quickly it's probably because I fell asleep, I've been working most of the night on things like this. Have a nice night/day yourself all, and thx again.

Comment: Bridge Edge Loops is probably the best way to do it, it will need additional clicks as you'll need to fill the first and the last faces. But you say that your shape is symmetrical, depending on the symmetry axis you may be able to extrude the vertices then select all and Mesh > Symmetrize, it would be much easier but it all depends on the symmetry, is your object symmetrical on the Y axis? Maybe share your file so that we can test: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: here's the file https://pasteall.org/blend/ed8827807da346ccaf978f55baf2bdb2
haven't played with mesh symmetrize, that could work. bridge edge loops is awkward since it's just 1 edge loop, but ig i could just delete something to make it 2 loops and try to bridge it that way, will try in the morning

Answer (score 0):

*Grid Fill* seems to work fine.

Select your top edge loop:

[image]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Grid Fill*. In the *Operator* box (pop-up box that appears on the bottom left of your 3D view and allows you to tweak the parameters for your last operation), put the *Span* value at 1:

[image]